# Why was my Groucho Marx question closed?

Tags: discussion, question-closure

Why was https://english.stackexchange.com/q/516777/334589 closed? I would've accepted [this comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/516777/what-did-groucho-marx-mean-by-i-wouldn-t-want-to-be-a-party-to-any-contract-whe#comment1254776_516777) if posted as answer.

> The usual Groucho Marx quote is "I don’t want to belong to any club that would have me as a member." I have always taken it to mean that if a club will accept even him as a member it must have low standards and thus not be worth joining. He meant it humorously. It is said that Abraham Lincoln made a similar statement about marriage. – nnnnnn Oct 29 at 6:45

Comment: You can see the close reason on [the timeline](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/516777/timeline) (which is difficult/impossible to find, I know. I only know about the timeline because I'm a mod).

Comment: Looking at the timeline, I don't think the question was closed.

Comment: @MattE.Эллен  Community is code for the roomba system methinks.

Comment: @Mari-LouA yes I think the automatic clean up process deleted the question because it has a negative score

Comment: [*Yesterday a question of mine, Is “shipping” today's equivalent of “matchmaking”?, which had been closed as a duplicate, was deleted automatically by the system.*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/328351)

Comment: Possibly, people reading the question thought that it was more appropriate for ELL, as being fairly obvious. //  Or even LiteratureSE. Comprehension – interpretation of / commentary on strings longer than say an idiom – can very easily be seen as not within ELU's remit.

Answer (score 4):

The question itself was not closed.

Stack Exchange as a whole has automatic systems in place that delete questions that meet certain criteria. (Affectionately known as the roomba.)

You can review the criteria here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/147791

Your question came under point 9:

> 9. The system will automatically delete negatively-scored, unlocked, and unanswered questions (both open and closed, including as duplicates) that are older than 30 days.

Your question has had a score of -1 since October the 29th, and was deleted on November the 30th.